# How to add DatePicker in a inputbox in a googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, datepicker, google-sheets, inputbox

I'm trying to add a datepicker in a InputBox in Google Script for a GoogleSheet, to retrieve the date value picked in a cell.

Do you have any ideas  how to do this ?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score -2):

Data >> Data Validation >> Criteria >> Date
[image]

Comment: The question is about creating a custom dialog box by using Google Apps Script.